# Create a PowerPoint template with variants - searching Microsoft's Variant Creator

Tags: office365, ms-office, powerpoint

I want to create a PowerPoint Template with variants for different colorstyles on single slides.

Now I am looking for the "Microsoft's Variant Creator beta tool". Has anyone it? 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/94957643-a699-4fcb-a955-1243e0691972/powerpoint-2013-design-variants?forum=officeitpro

Another method would be to create a own super theme, but I only found this decent tutorial.

https://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/themes/editing-super-themes-with-xml.html

I don't now why this feature is so bad supported from MS. Are there any better option at the moment to create a template with different accents colors?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft never released the beta super-theme tool and appears to have removed even the beta tool; I've searched for it a number of times and had no luck finding it. Incidentally, superthemes and variants are pretty much the same deal; you must create a supertheme in order to enable variants.

Another approach would be to distribute color theme files and possible an add-in that would allow users to choose the correct color theme easily.